# Marker is flickering in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, kotlin, google-maps-markers

I've implemented an app that is based on safety purposes. This app is for the two roles i.e A and B. Both users can track the location of each other. For user A, I've implemented the Mapbox and for user B I've implemented the Google Map.

For A, Mapbox provides the default real-time navigation and for B, I've used signal R which provides the location of user A. So I can navigate marker to that particular location of the A.

I'm facing the issue while getting the location from the SignalR. But Marker is flickering.

I've used code to move the marker as below.

```
private val mMoveCarLocation = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (intent != null) {
                val handler = Handler()
                //Code to move car along latitude and longitude
                handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {
                        try {
                            //post again
                            Log.d("tess", "inside run ")
                            val targetLocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

                            val latitude = java.lang.Double.valueOf(
                                intent.getStringExtra(
                                    GlobalVariables.PROVIDE_A_LATITUDE
                                )
                            )
                            val longitude =
                                java.lang.Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(GlobalVariables.PROVIDE_A_LONGITUDE))
                            targetLocation.latitude = latitude
                            targetLocation.longitude = longitude
                            animateMarkerNew(targetLocation)
                            mActivityUserMapBinding!!.txtTime.setText(
                                intent.getStringExtra(
                                    REMAINING_TIME
                                )
                            )
                        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                            Log.d("tess", "call back removed")
                            //removed callbacks
                            handler.removeCallbacks(this)
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000)
            }
        }
    }
```

Animate the Marker

```
fun animateMarkerNew(destination: Location) {
        if (viewModel.mMarker != null) {
            val startPosition = viewModel.mMarker.position
            val endPosition = LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)

            val startRotation = viewModel.mMarker.rotation
            val latLngInterpolator = UserMapViewModel.LatLngInterpolatorNew.LinearFixed()

            val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0F, 1F)
            valueAnimator.duration = 3000 // duration 3 second
            valueAnimator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
                try {
                    val v = animation.animatedFraction
                    val newPosition =
                        latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition)
                    viewModel.mMarker.setPosition(newPosition)

                    handler = Handler()
                    handler!!.postDelayed(Runnable {
                        viewModel.googleMap!!.moveCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                                CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(newPosition)
                                    // .zoom(15.5f)
                                    .zoom(17.5f)
                                    .build()
                            )
                        )

                        viewModel.mMarker.rotation = viewModel.getBearing(
                            startPosition,
                            LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)
                        )
                    }, 800)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    //I don't care atm..
                }
            }
            valueAnimator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                }
            })
            valueAnimator.start()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static void animateMarker(LocationInfo destination, Marker marker, float bearning) {
    if (marker != null) {
        LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
        LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

        float startRotation = marker.getRotation();

        LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(1000); // duration 1 second
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                try {
                    float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                    LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                    marker.setPosition(newPosition);
//                        marker.setRotation(computeRotation(v, startRotation, bearning));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // I don't care atm..
                }
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}



 interface LatLngInterpolator {
 LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolator {
    @Override
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
        double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
        double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
        // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
        if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
            lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
        }
        double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
        return new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }
}
```

}